# How to scroll vertically in hybdrid app using appium java

Tags: android, webview, appium

[image]

I am automating hybrid app. I want click on sign out which is not visible on the page and hence I need to scroll down to click on it. I am trying with below code but it's not working and I am using Java client 5.0.4 Appium server 1.7.2 and selenium 3.9.1 and Java jdk version 1.8.0_161. Can any one please help

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<String, String>();
        scrollObject.put("direction", "down");
        js.executeScript("mobile: scroll", scrollObject); 
        do 
        {
        try{
        ele1.click();
        break;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            js.executeScript("mobile: scroll", scrollObject); 
        }
        } while(true);
```

Answer (score -3):

Check out this link. I have not used it for hybrid app but it may help you. It provides solution to scroll page vertically using Android Driver.
 http://www.qaautomated.com/2016/02/how-to-scroll-in-appium.html

I have tried this code and it worked for me to click on object which is not visible on screen. You can try this.

```
MobileElement abc = (MobileElement) driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView("
                  +"new UiSelector().text(\"Country\"));"));
          abc.click();
```

Replace "Country" with your text or resource-id. Check this link for how to use UiSelector which helps me to find this solution. http://www.automationtestinghub.com/uiselector-android/

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Re post when  previous answer is deleted.

Comment: This is the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50172586/4826457) you have posted containing the same domain link.. Are you affiliated with the site?

Comment: Same answer is posted by mistake. Now I have edited this and gives solution.